# php exec() hangs

Tags: php, windows, iis, batch-file

I'm running php 5.2.0 on IIS 7.

Within this environment I tried to fork a process using php exec method as follows.
exec("background_processes\process_sePos_report.bat)

It runs fine for sometime but then the process in this case cmd.exe hangs in the server. It won't do anything until the server is restarted.

I also changed the code according to the below bug but the issue didn't resolve.
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44942

Can someone please help me on this issue.

Thanks

Comment: so what does the .bat do, does it process something for a long time or does it return immediately?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the limit by which time .bat should be finished, you could use [set_time_limit()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). My *guess* is that it *might* help in preventing such hangs from happening on windows, where it measures the activity spent on exec() calls, too.